# How to share wsdl and xsd files between different projects?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

We use C# project as a server for soap web service and java project as a client.

Could you tell me what is the best way to share `WSDL` and `XSD` files between these two projects? so we don't have to make a local copy of them in our java client every time these files change in C# project.

I thought about creating maven project with only `WSDL` and `XSD` files in the resources folder, wrap it to the jar file and publish it to Artifactory or maven shared repo. But I don't know if it's the right way, cause C# doesn't support jars.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Could you tell me what is the best way to share WSDL and XSD files between these two projects?

It's not necessary to place these files in a project at all because WSDL+XSD exists independant of any programming language or project and can be edited directly via tools such as *Stylus Studio* (which doesn't have a dependency on Java or .NET).  This is important for **schema-first** methodologies.

Create a common folder in source control repo into which to place the WSDL and XSD.  The repo can then house both C# and Java code and refer by whatever means to the common WSDL/XSD folder.

e.g. repo folder layout

```
bin
docs
schemas         <--- place here
src
|-- common
    |-- schemas <--- or perhaps here
|-- cpp
|-- java
```

The exact layout is not important so long as:

1. there is only ever **one** copy of the WSDL and XSDs (the **source of truth**)
2. there is an easy way for your code to get to the models

That or create a second repo just for WSDL definitions

For more great SOA ideas check out this book - SOA Design Patterns by Thomas Erl.

[image]

Comment: I can't combine C# and Java projects in one repo, unfortunately. Maybe there is some other way without combining them?

Comment: If I create a second repo just for WSDL, how can I get access to it to build pojo entities in C# and java projects?

Comment: @BorisMitioglov not sure why you can't have a single source code repository for multiple programming languages.  But if not to answer your second question, checkout the WSDL repo in a known location and have the C# and Java projects refer to the folder by relative or absolute folder paths

Comment: I need it to be remote, being deployed somewhere and I don't want any dependencies between projects locations. So maybe there is some way to publish it like a maven dependency and then download it as a maven dependency?

Comment: @BorisMitioglov I'm not sure but it sounds like an excellent _new question_ to post on SO.  Consider accepting my answer if you think it deserves it based on the original question posed.  Otherweise its kinda borderline _[Change to question invalidates my answer, what to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286803/change-to-question-invalidates-my-answer-what-to-do)_.  I'd be happy to help in the new post.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your answer but I don't think it's the best way of doing that because it's introducing dependencies between project locations.  I was asking about the best way.

Comment: @BorisMitioglov what are you talking about?  I already answered _"what is the best way to `share` WSDL and XSD files between these two projects"_ and if _"share"_ doesn't imply _"introducing dependencies"_ I don't know what does.  The alternative is to give each project its own copy and in the EAI world that **isn't** a best practice.  Check out the book above